# Making Search results better

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a very basic search code for searching the users from database and displaying them onto the page. Everything goes fine in fetching the data from database and getting it displayed, but the error is that the searched result user on being clicked doesn't show that respective users profile. Instead it shows a random profile with name as `$username` which is due to this line of code:

```
$output .= '<div><a href= "profile.php?u=$username">'.$fname.' '.$lname.'</a></div>';
```

Please check the code below and help me out in making it open a respective user's profile who is being searched for.

```
<?php
 $username="";
$output = '';
if (isset($_POST['search'])){
$search_query = $_POST['search'];
$search_q = $_POST['search'];
$search_query = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","", $search_query);
$search_q = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","", $search_q);
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username LIKE '%$search_query%' OR last_name LIKE '%$search_query%'") or die ("Could not search");
$count = mysql_num_rows($query);
if($count == 0) {
    $output = 'No Results Found.';
}
else{
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $fname = $row['first_name'];
    $lname = $row['last_name'];
    $id = $row['id'];
    $output .= '<div><a href= "profile.php?u=$username">'.$fname.' '.$lname.'</a></div>';
}
}
}

?>
<?php echo("$output");?>
```

Comment: `<a href= "profile.php?u=$username">'` you are not setting the username

Comment: well here username needs to be the one that is searched.

Comment: Fine then add `<a href= "profile.php?u=$row[ 'username' ]">'

Comment: error occured:
syntax error, unexpected 'username' (T_VARIABLE)

Comment: For the love of humanity, please stop this.

Answer (score 1):

You are not setting the username variable

Change:

```
<a href= "profile.php?u=$username">'
```

To

```
$output .= "<div><a href='profile.php?u=$username'>$fname $lname</a></div>";
```

Comment: Try that, you are mixing the single and double quotes

Comment: hurray it worked!!

but one error still occurs the some profile contents on the searched user are not shown instead the logged in user profile contents are shown

Answer (score 0):

You never set `$username` to any meaningful value.

```
$username="";
//...
$output .= '<div><a href= "profile.php?u=$username">'.$fname.' '.$lname.'</a></div>';
```

So the resulting link will be:

```
profile.php?u=
```

Or, alternatively, if the variable isn't being expanded, then the resulting link will be:

```
profile.php?u=$username
```

(You can validate this in your browser.)

What that page does and how it decides what to display when no `u` value (or an invalid value) is provided is up to the code on that page.

Comment: it not even searches properly

Comment: @sanchitg: Perhaps you can be more specific about the problem you're trying to describe?